# How to get substring based on a character and starting to read the string from the right

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I have the following values on a column:

```
DB3-0800-VRET,
DB3-0800-IC,
IB-TZ-850-IB,
O11FS-OB ...
```

From each value I want to remove the last part after the dash.
I need to have the following result:

```
DB3-0800-VRET -> DB3-0800,
DB3-0800-IC   -> DB3-0800,
O11FS-OB      -> O11FS
```

I tried to work with the SPLIT_PART function of RedShift but I didn't have any luck.
If someone knows a regex to select the part I need I'd be grateful.

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Those are two very different DBMS (even though Redshift is based on Postgres)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's Redshift, but since I know Redshift is based on Postgres I also included it in a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both Postgres and Redshift, you should be able to use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(str, '-[^-]+$', '')
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. In redshift this query is not valid. When I remove the last quotation marks, I only get the part I want to remove. Can you let me know who can I select the substring without including the part I'm getting in return now.

Comment: @PlarentHaxhidauti . . . It should work:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_REPLACE.html.

Comment: Thank you I made a spelling mistake in my query. It's working:))